# Setting SortKey of JTable with duplicate values does not work

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, tablerowsorter

I have a problem with setting SortKeys in java. I used a SortKey from an existing JTable and set it to another one, but somehow it is not working when there are duplicate values in a column, for example the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are sorted correctly, but the values 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 differ in the their order in the JTable.

PS: I already have setMaxSortKeys(int max) on 1.

Comment: no idea what you talking about, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)  demonstraded a.m. described issue

Comment: `setMaxSortKeys(int)`  Where did you find that method?

Comment: here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#setSortKeys(java.util.List)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that initial ordering of the rows is different in two tables. It is also possible that the sorting algorithm used to sort the tables is not stable. In these cases you can't expect the order to be same for duplicate column values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that feedback, I had in mind that both have the same original (initial) data in the exact same order, but some elements differed => now I need to know what to do.